# Firebase cloud function onRequest() not being triggering

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mpesa

My firebase cloud function is not working as expected and this is causing a headache, for me and my freelance client(my first freelance job).

The following is my cloud function. It is supposed to receive payload payment data in json format. This data is to be extracted and saved in firestore document. I confirm if payment is successful or not using the data written in firestore document.

Note: It was working as expected until yesterday morning, when payments I could no longer confirm payment status. I could not confirm payment status because the data that is supposed to be written to the document, is not written.

The payload looks similar to this:

```
    {
 "Result": {
    "ResultType": 0,
    "ResultCode": 2001,
    "ResultDesc": "The initiator information is invalid.",
    "OriginatorConversationID": "29112-34801843-1",
    "ConversationID": "AG_20191219_00006c6fddb15123addf",
    "TransactionID": "NLJ0000000",
    "ReferenceData": {
      "ReferenceItem": {
          "Key": "QueueTimeoutURL",
          "Value": "https:\/\/internalsandbox.safaricom.co.ke\/mpesa\/b2cresults\/v1\/submit"
        }
    }
 }
}
```

My cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./service_account_key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: '<removed>'
});

console.log('WE ARE ABOUT TO BEGIN');
exports.paymentCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Checking if req body exists');
    console.log(req.body);

    try {
        // Check if the request body is undefined
        if (!req.body || !req.body.Result) {
            throw new Error('Request body is undefined.');
        }

        // Get the result from the request body
        const result = req.body.Result;

        console.log('Received payload: ', result);

        const responseCode = result.ResultCode;
        const mCheckoutRequestID = result.ConversationID;
        const mResultDesc = result.ResultDesc;

        if (responseCode === 0) {
            console.log('Successful transaction.');

            // Access the ResultParameters
            const resultParameters = result.ResultParameters.ResultParameter;

            let mReceipt;
            let mPhonePaidFrom;
            let mAmountPaid;

            resultParameters.forEach(entry => {
                switch (entry.Key) {
                    case 'MpesaReceiptNumber':
                        mReceipt = entry.Value;
                        break;
                    case 'PhoneNumber':
                        mPhonePaidFrom = entry.Value;
                        break;
                    case 'Amount':
                        mAmountPaid = entry.Value;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });

            const mEntryDetails = {
                receipt: mReceipt,
                phone: mPhonePaidFrom,
                amount: mAmountPaid,
                result: mResultDesc
            };

            // Find the document initialized from the client device containing the CheckoutRequestID
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
            const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('user_payments/payment_info/response_code_zero').doc(mCheckoutRequestID);
            const doc = await docRef.get();

            if (doc.exists) {
                // Save transaction details in DB
                await docRef.update(mEntryDetails);
                console.log('Updated document: ', docRef.path);
            } else {
                console.log('No document found matching the CheckoutRequestID: ', mCheckoutRequestID);

                // Persist the data somewhere for reference.
                await admin.firestore().collection('user_payments/payment_info/response_code_zero').doc(mCheckoutRequestID).set(mEntryDetails);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Failed transaction.');

            const mEntryDetails = {
                receipt: 'No receipt',
                result: 'Transaction failed'
            };

            // Find the document initialized from the client device containing the CheckoutRequestID
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
            const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('user_payments/payment_info/response_code_zero').doc(mCheckoutRequestID);
            const doc = await docRef.get();

            if (doc.exists) {
                // Save transaction details in DB
                await docRef.update(mEntryDetails);
                console.log('Updated document: ', docRef.path);
            } else {
                console.log('No document found matching the CheckoutRequestID: ', mCheckoutRequestID);

                // Persist the data somewhere for reference.
                await admin.firestore().collection('user_payments/payment_info/response_code_zero').doc(mCheckoutRequestID).set(mEntryDetails);
            }
        }

        // Send back a message that we've successfully processed the payment
        res.json({ result: `Payment for ${mCheckoutRequestID} response received.` });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Function error: ', error);
        // Retry the request using exponential backoff.
        if (!res.headersSent) {
            res.set('Retry-After', '30').status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error.' });
        }
    }
});
```

Upon checking my logs, I get this:

```
{
insertId: "647076a10006a986947418b6"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/<removed>/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-05-26T09:06:41.442233503Z"
resource: {2}
textPayload: "WE ARE ABOUT TO BEGIN"
timestamp: "2023-05-26T09:06:41.436614Z"
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "region": "europe-west2",
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Project structure:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/26/2023   3:26 PM                .dart_tool
d-----         1/19/2023  10:43 PM                .idea
d-----         3/27/2023   5:15 PM                .vscode
d-----         4/25/2023   4:16 PM                android
d-----         5/22/2023   1:56 PM                assets
d-----         5/26/2023   3:28 PM                build
d-----         5/26/2023   2:03 PM                functions
d-----         1/19/2023  10:43 PM                ios
d-----          3/7/2023  10:10 AM                lib
d-----         1/19/2023  10:43 PM                linux
d-----         1/19/2023  10:43 PM                macos
d-----         5/26/2023   1:30 AM                node_modules
d-----         1/19/2023  10:43 PM                test
d-----         5/13/2023   3:24 PM                web
d-----         1/19/2023  10:43 PM                windows
```

**Test on firebase emulator:**

Command I ran on terminal:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "http://localhost:5001/<removed>/us-central1/paymentCallback" -ContentType "application/json" -InFile ".\payload.json"

result
------
Payment for exampleConversationID response recei...
```

Results:

```
>  WE ARE ABOUT TO BEGIN
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-paymentCallback"
>  Checking if req body exists
>  {
>    Result: {
>      ResultCode: 0,
>      ConversationID: 'exampleConversationID',      
>      ResultDesc: 'exampleResultDesc',
>      ResultParameters: { ResultParameter: [Array] }
>    }
>  }
>  Received payload:  {
>    ResultCode: 0,
>    ConversationID: 'exampleConversationID',        
>    ResultDesc: 'exampleResultDesc',
>    ResultParameters: { ResultParameter: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
>  }
>  Successful transaction.
>  Updated document:  user_payments/payment_info/response_code_zero/exampleConversationID
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-paymentCallback" in 7408.2326ms
```

Comment: Before posting all the code check whether the normal [onRequest function](https://codefile.io/f/RTaA4sHK26) works or not using firebase emulator. If work then there must be an issue with the configuration of your function for that also share `firebase.json` and your project structure.

Comment: Hi @RohitKharche, I have added more information above.  Tests run as expected on emulator, function is triggered. On my device, function is not triggered.

Comment: You still haven't shared the `firebase.json` and the project structure with checking the normal barebone onRequest function works or not .

Comment: @RohitKharche I have added firebase.json and project structure.

Comment: Have you deployed your project? Are you connecting to the right region? What happens when you visit the Cloud Function directly in your browser? When checking if the function succeeds by looking at Firestore, are you checking the emulator or the server as appropriate?

Comment: @samthecodingman It is deployed. Visiting the cloud function url on the browser give me "internal server error". When testing on local server with test payload, it all works great, the function is called. On a physical device AND postman, function is not called. I get "internal server error". I monitor firebase emulator when testing on local server.

Comment: @samthecodingman It is an app build with flutter. Upon payment, a payload with the payment details are sent to the callbackurl (cloud function). It was working as intended until yesterday morning.